# read input by user seperated by line breaks, spaces etc

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner

im struggling with the input part of the below question.

Question: The input stream contains a set of integer numbers Ai (0 ≤ Ai ≤ 1018). The numbers are separated by any number of spaces and line breaks. A size of the input stream does not exceed 256 KB.

how do i read the input from the user which are separated by line breaks, spaces etc. how do i make sure the input stream doesnot exceed 256 KB? 
and how do i make sure that a particular input will be the last value entered by the user so that the program and proceed for execution?

the input can be given in anyway, any number not exceeding 10^8,EX:  first input can be given as say 1 and in the same line the second input can be given as 34 separated by 3 spaces from the first input. then 2nd line and the 3rd line are empty and again in the fourth line, there can a number say 225345 which is the 3rd input. so once all the inputs are given by the user, i have to take them, arrange them into one list or array and perform some operations on them.

example:

1427   0

876652098643267843

5276538

kindly help. thanks

Comment: any number of spaces/line breaks. So it could also be zero spaces? Could you give us a more concise example of your expected input and output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick if there is at least one space between each number

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("data.txt")); // or new Scanner(System.in) for reading from command line.
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    int number = scanner.nextInt();
    if (number<0||number>1018)
        break;
    list.add(number);
}
scanner.close();
System.out.println(list);
```

Example: (data.txt)

```
145     358
    94 2
     13 1205 158    489
```

Output:

```
[145, 358, 94, 2, 13, 1205, 158, 489]
```

Comment: yes, this is how it should be. but cant the inputs be taken from the console itself ? instead of a text file ?

Comment: and there might be empty lines too which should be ignored.

Comment: @Ascalonian  yes i will surely do it, let my doubts be clarified :)

Comment: @neils billen, how do i take all the values into a array or a list ? how can we do it.

Comment: @DevDev If you have additional questions, you should place them in the OP or make a new question.

Comment: @DevDev empty lines are ignored automatically. You can read from System.in by creating a scanner like this new Scanner(System.in)

Comment: @Niels Billen - one  last query Niels, im able to enter the input in anyway.. but how do i terminate it or how do i close my input console to get the output?.. it is continously taking the inputs

Comment: @DevDev, I edited the example so it stops when a number smaller than 0 or larger than 1018 is encountered

Answer (score 0):

Use a java.util.Scanner to read the sequence of longs (because 10^18 > Integer.MAX_VALUE):

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(input);
while (scanner.hasNextLong()) {
  long number = scanner.nextLong();
  if (number < 1 || number > 1_000_000_000_000_000_000L)
    throw new RuntimeException("input out of range: " + number);
}
```

To validate the input stream size you can reuse the CountingInputStream from [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries) or [Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io), or code your own. Note that, due to internal buffering in Scanner, you may end up reading more than 256 KB of input.

```
CountingInputStream input = new CountingInputStream(System.in);
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(input);
while (scanner.hasNextLong() && input.getCount() < 256 * 1024) { ... }
```

Ensuring that a particular input will be the last value requires you to pick a delimiter. I'd use a number out of the acceptable input, say, -1:

```
CountingInputStream input = new CountingInputStream(System.in);
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(input);
while (scanner.hasNextLong() && input.getCount() < 256 * 1024) {
  long number = scanner.nextLong();
  if (number == -1)
     break;
  if (number < 1 || number > 1_000_000_000_000_000_000L)
    throw new RuntimeException("input out of range: " + number);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: sorry.. i got it... it was my mistake writing it.. it should be 10power18

Comment: im wondering now.. what if the range is between 1 and 10^18, how do you stop the inputs?

Comment: You can still use -1 to stop the input as it falls outside the permissible range. I'll edit the answer to reflect the correct range.

Comment: yes i understood, i actually forgot that we can use -1 to break it. and i used it now. but my only concern is that CountingInputStream is not showing up in java

Comment: Oh, as I indicated in the answer, [CountingInputStream](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/io/CountingInputStream.html) as used here comes from the [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) library. There is a [similar class](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/index.html) in [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/). You can reuse those implementations or roll your own.

Comment: when i try to use the CountingInputStream and submit my solution in a online compiler, it is not able to take this as it a external jar file (it is working in my comp as i've downloaded it)... so it there anyway.. wherein i can control my input stream to 256 KB without CountingInputStream ? kindly help